# Is there a way to run c# code inside VSCode Editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I would like to know if there is a way to run C# code in VSCode the editor ?
Like you do when you press F12 on chrome and can run some JS code in the console.

The only way I found was to use [CodeRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension which need [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/) to be installed which need [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). It's too much things to installed for a simple feature.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .NET Core CLI, run the following command:

```
dotnet run
```

Comment: I think this is only for running the actual projet. Not to run a small chunk of code.